# Usage of "все" vs "ещё"?

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова

So I just came across the following sentence:

> Прошло 2 года,а я все слушаю

If I had to make a guess I'd translate this to something like:

> It's been two years and still i'm listening

It appears that, все is being used instead  ещё, so my questions is: what's the difference between them?

Comment: Your translation is correct. You can also say "а я все еще слушаю" or "а я еще слушаю": all three phrases have same meaning. From my point of view (I am native Russian speaker) "а я все еще слушаю" is the most used one, and "а я всё слушаю" sounds like something used in books or used by poets, but people will understand you in any case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think **всё** alone in the sense of **ещё** is bookish, i use it in mundane conversations, and your sentence in Russian is perfectly mundane. But it does in my view have a certain tinge of meaning.

**Ещё** is a straight ***still***, but **всё ещё** often and **всё** almost exclusively are used in combination with alternative conjunction **a** and have a connotation of **can't stop *+ gerund***, that is continuing to do something almost against all odds, against one's will, or obsessively. And in **всё** alone this connotation is stronger. It's usually said with a shade of regret, helplessness or irony.

Eg.

> Она его видеть не хочет, а он всё ходит к ней
>
> За окном уже стояла глубокая ночь, а я всё читал

In both, your Russian sentence and in this example **всё** is used in a clause contrasting with another clause to mean that something *continues* to be done or to happen despite circumstance described in another clause.

PS: It occurred to me that this **всё** could be a variant of **всё равно** which in contrastive clauses means ***despite that*** and also ***still***. So

> Прошло 2 года, а я **всё** слушаю

AND

> Прошло 2 года, а я **всё** ***равно*** слушаю

although not fully synonymous are still (apropos) very close in meaning

Answer (score 3):

**Прошло 2 года, а я все слушаю** is basically a shortened version of **Прошло 2 года, а я все ещё слушаю**

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is.